# Assembly: writing multiple lines into a buffer

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have a problem with my second ever program in Assembly. The task is to read multiple lines of text from a keyboard and write them down into a buffer (.comm). After an empty line is entered, program should echo in a loop each previously typed line of text. A limit for one line of text is 100 charcters. However, I get a "program received signal sigsegv segmentation fault / 0x00000000006000a5 in check ()" error message.

My idea is to create a buffer of size 5050 bytes. Each line of text can have at most 100 characters. Here is a visual structure of the buffer:

```
[First line     ][0][Second line      ][0][Short            ][0][Text             ][0]
```

**UPDATE:** According to Jester's reply (thanks!), I've slightly modified my idea for the program. I abandoned the idea of 100 bytes per line. I'll simply place them one after another, simply separating them with a special character (0). So a new structure of the buffer would be:

```
[First line of text][0][No matter how long it is][0][short][0]
```

However, I've got a problem with appending the special "0" character to the BUFFER in "add_separator" part. I also wonder if it's really necessary since we add the "\n" new line indicator into the BUFFER asswell?

Also, the part when I check if the entered line of code is empty never returns true (empty line state) so the program keeps loading and loading new lines. Did I miss anything?

Here is an updated bit of code:

```
SYSEXIT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
STDOUT = 1
STDIN = 0
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

.align 32

.data #data section

    .comm BUFFER, 5050  #my buffer of a size of 5050 bytes
    BUFFER_len = 5050


.global _start

_start:

mov $0,%esi

read:

    mov $SYSREAD, %eax
    mov $STDIN, %ebx
    mov BUFFER(%esi), %ecx
    mov $1, %edx
    int $0x80   

check:

    cmp $0, %eax        # check if entered line is empty
    je end          # if yes, end program

    lea BUFFER(%esi), %ecx  # move the latest character for comparison
    cmp '\n', %ecx      # check if it's a line end 
    inc %esi        # increment the iterator
    je end
    jmp read

end:

    mov $SYSWRITE, %eax
    mov $STDOUT, %ebx
    mov $BUFFER, %ecx
    mov $BUFFER_len, %edx

    int $0x80

    mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
    mov $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Filip

Comment: Please add tag with OS / CPU architecture (looks like Windows/x86) to me.

Comment: @hivert it's certainly linux as indicated by the system calls

Comment: @Jester: Ok ! I've never written an OS call in assembly ! I'm only doing number crunching (in particular SIMD). For OS call C is much easier.

Comment: I don't know why you would write this program in assembly?  But I'll assume you have a good reason.   *Don't* code raw system calls yourself.  Use the C library's wrappers: `call read`, `call write`, `call _exit`, etc.  They insulate you from low-level ABI details you don't want to have to care about (for instance, those system call numbers are only correct for x86-32), they know how to set `errno`, and they use the most efficient available trap sequence (on x86, usually `sysenter` or `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`).

Comment: Also, if you're going to write assembly by hand you need to know the ABI: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/abi386-4.pdf (x86-32), http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf (x86-64).

Comment: Hi! It is of course 64bit Linux, my apologize for not adding the information. @Zack That is my University subject "Computer Architecture". Writing it in any other language would probably take several seconds (depending on how you type!). As for wrappers, I prefer to use the ones our teacher showed to us. He may be suspicious if I suddenly switch! I've also updated my original post guys. Thanks!

Comment: You really don't need the zero, you have the `\n` as you said. The empty line contains 1 character, the `\n` itself. To detect an empty line you have to remember the previous character. The `read` system call returns zero on `EOF`. `mov BUFFER(%esi), %ecx` is wrong, you want to pass the address, so use `lea`.

Comment: If this is 64-bit x86, then your system call numbers **are** wrong, and so is your calling convention.  If your teacher is telling you not to use the C library then your teacher is wrong.  **Use the C library.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm skipping the extra zero then, it's indeed unnecessary. I've also updated my code according to your comment (lea instruction) but I cannot find anywhere how would I go about checking the latest character there. As for the empty line - I'm sorry but I'm not quite sure what you mean.. Could you please elaborate? I'd truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Zack, the OPs system call numbers are correct.  You can write 32bit code and execute on a 64bit system using `int 80H`!  What is the sense of learning the "dark corners" of the CPU if one "HAS TO USE" the C Library?

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. Trust me, you don't want to use `esp` as a general purpose register as a beginner
2. The `read` system call will read at most as many bytes as you specify (in this case `BUFFER_LEN`) and it will return the number of bytes read. You should pass in 1 instead, so you can read char-by-char.
3. Adding `100` for the next word (you really mean line, right?) isn't terribly useful, just append each character continuously since that's how you want to print them too.
4. `cmp '\n', %al` would try to use the `'\n'` as an address, you want `cmp $'\n', %al` to use an immediate
5. Learn to use a debugger to find your own mistakes
6. using `jg` to jump over a `jle` is really unnecessary, just keep the `jle` and let the execution continue normally otherwise

Comment: Hi there! Thank you so much for your reply, it really helped me. According to your tips, I've slightly modified the plan for the program and the example code I've come up so far. However, my idea is to insert a line break indicator (0) after each line of text (detecting the $'\n' first, as I described in comments in the code above) but I cannot find a proper way anywhere and my version if obviously wrong: "mov $0, BUFFER(%esi)". Also, I cannot figure out why the first check for "Empty Line" does never return true, even if I just hit enter without any characters while typing?